# Mist password not working. Is there a way to open a new account?

Tags: mist, recovery, encryption

I have a mac. How do I delete mist and re-download it + blockchain so I can start fresh? My original password is not working (only 1 eth in it so not worried about loss).

If it needs to be deleted through terminal and you can direct me through the process it would be much appreciated : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a new account in Mist Ethereum Wallet dapp:

- Make sure that Ethereum Wallet is started
- Make sure you are on the Wallets tab
- Click "+ Add Account" under the Accounts section
- Type a new password
- Once you have a new account, make sure to make a backup

(No need to delete the blockchain just to make a new account.)

Answer (score 4):

Mist is actually not directly connected to the blockchain or your account.  It's just a UI over top of the actual Ethereum client.

If you look on your mac you should see the folder `~/Library/Ethereum`. It actually contains the blockchain and your account keys in the `keystore` sub-directory. **DO NOT DELETE THE FILES IN THE KEYSTORE DIRECTORY** they are the keys to your account. If fact you should back them up to a secure place.

You can delete Mist simply by deleting the Mist folder.  But I wouldn't delete the `~/Library/Ethereum` folder unless you want to download the entire blockchain again.

As for your original password.  If you lost that, you're pretty much out of luck.

Comment: Thank you. My password is gone. I need a "new" account. Do I do this by deleting the blockchain and download all over again?

Comment: No.  I would highly suggest that you read the Ethereum introduction guide.